# No folder permission options/lock icon in macOS Catalina

Tags: mac, catalina

On a 2018 Mac mini that came pre-loaded with macOS Catalina, when I get info on a folder, under "Sharing & Permissions" it only displays "You can read and write" but there are none of the standard read/write columns nor any lock icon like in previous versions.

What am I missing? Am I not logged in as administrator? I've never encountered this before.

Comment: Did you just acquire this Mac? Is it second hand?

Comment: Is the folder in your system disk?  If not, the reason will be permissions not enabled on the disk.  If on system disk, please post the Get Info window.

Comment: @Gilby: that seems to be exactly the problem. If I get info on the Documents folder for a system user, I get the standard permissions options; if I do the same for a folder on an external SSD, I only get "You can read and write". When I get info on the external drive itself, it says only "You have custom access" with no other options. So I have a disk permissions issue (which I didn't have on my iMac running 10.12).

Comment: @Tetsujin: bought new

Comment: I've just found the same question asked on Apple discussions:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251433211

Their solution was to reformat the drive?! I have 1.5Tb of data shared across the 3 SSDs...this can't be the solution. Is there not a global perfs/permissions setting in Catalina that gives normal read/write access to drives?

Again, none of this was an issue on 10.12.

Comment: Ah - you didn't say this was on an external drive. Answer added. BTW, the solution on that discussion is a bit misinformed. Sure it will work, but it's a bit heavy-handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions you see will depend how the drive is formatted.

If it's HFS+ or APFS, on any non-boot drive, you should see a line at the bottom of the Get Info window marked "ignore ownership on this volume'. If it's NTFS this will be missing. Any kind of FAT & it will also be missing, along with the entire permissions 'box' which would usually be at the bottom.
NTFS cannot hold the full set of unix/Mac permissions & FAT can't hold any of them.

See this example, from left to right APFS boot drive, HFS+, NTFS & FAT32.
I also have [Paragon NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) installed, which allows writing to NTFS [which the Mac cannot do natively] & which may affect how the permissions show for NTFS [I'm not certain].

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the answer. I don't recall seeing this on 10.12—though I wasn't looking for it either. I'll check out Paragon.